# restore database from .bson file for python

Tags: python, database, mongodb, bson

I tried to read a bson file using the following command :

```
import bson
input_dir='/path/to/file/dir/'
bson_stats =open(os.path.join(input_dir,'stats.bson'),'rb')
bson_stats = bson.loads(bson_stats.read())
```

When I try to get access to `bson_stats` , I got only one line of data, but not the whole data.

This is my first time to play with bson file. My question is :

- how to get access to the whole data in bson file ?

Link to the `stats.bson` file :

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N71hRafOm_6xWNsUfxcr5Sm0fQwydd1a/view?usp=sharing
```

Comment: How do you know there's more data in there? Probably not a problem here, but naming your `open()` variable `bson_stats` which is the same as where you want to save your data in. Is probably not a good idea. Might get conflicts if you start doing this on a regular basis. For instance iterating over a file, a loop etc. You'll be replacing the handle you're doing the `.read()` on. Again, maybe not here. But a bad habbit.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Comment: @Torxed this command is start for me. I don't know how to restore the data from bson at all. If you have a better idea, feel free to suggest it ! I have a link of my file if you want to try it. I know the file have more data according to the website where I got it. Also, the file size if about 24MB. Thank you.

Comment: @desertnaut Oups sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BSON (Binary JSON) Encoding and Decoding](https://api.mongodb.com/python/2.7.2/api/bson/index.html?highlight=bson#bson.decode_all)

```
>>> with open('stats.bson', 'rb') as f:
...     data = bson.decode_all(f.read())
...     print data
[{u'CodeGare': u'057', u'TrainEnRetard': 0, u'GareJour': u'2018-03-23_057', u'TotalTrains': 0, u'Date': u'2018-03-23', u'_id': ObjectId('5ab5a312d909c48f43e26cb5')}, {u'CodeGare': u'063', u'TrainEnRetard': 4, u'GareJour': u'2018-03-23_063', u'TotalTrains': 4, u'Date': u'2018-03-23', u'_id': ObjectId('5ab5a312d909c48f43e26cb8')}, {u'CodeGare': u'067', u'TrainEnRetard': 4, u'GareJour': u'2018-03-23_067', u'TotalTrains': 4, u'Date': u'2018-03-23', u'_id': ObjectId('5ab5a312d909c48f43e26cbb')}, {u'CodeGare': u'071', u'TrainEnRetard': 4, u'GareJour': u'2018-03-23_071', u'TotalTrains': 4, u'Date': u'2018-03-23', u'_id': ObjectId('5ab5a312d909c48f43e26cbe')}, {u'CodeGare': u'077', u'TrainEnRetard': 3, u'GareJour': u'2018-03-23_077', u'TotalTrains': 3, u'Date': u'2018-03-23', u'_id': ObjectId('5ab5a312d909c48f43e26cc1')}
```